# Force hover state secondary element on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover, click

quick question from a complete JS noobie.

On a site, I have an image of a product consisting of basically two parts, then I have a row of small .png thumbnails `.colorthumbnail` of those separate parts with transparent backgrounds. In the CSS I set it so that when hovering the thumbnails, it enables the `.colorzoom` class that overlays a big version of the same color option over the original product picture using `position: absolute`.

HTML:

```
<div class="coloroptions">
                <div class="j210desertsand">
                <div class="colorthumbnail">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="colorpicker">
                <img src="img/products/colors/j210desertsand.png"></a>
                <span class="colorzoom"><img src="img/products/colors/j210desertsand.png">
                </span></div></div>
                <div class="j210platinum">
                <div class="colorthumbnail">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="colorpicker">
                <img src="img/products/colors/j210platinum.png"></a>
                <span class="colorzoom"><img src="img/products/colors/j210platinum.png">
                </span></div></div>
</div>
```

The `<div class="j210desertsand">`classes are simply there so I can easily hide a single color option using CSS and the next colour will line up. The anchor points are there cause after some research I found I should actually make the thumbnails clickable and with `a href="javascript:void(0)"` they don't actually link anywhere or reload the page.

CSS: (Excuse the mess, I'm inexperienced)

```
.coloroptions {
    width: 60%;
    margin-left: 40%;
}

.colorthumbnail {
    margin-left: -45%;
}

.colorthumbnail img {
    float: left;
    max-width: 16%;
    padding-right: 5px;
    position: relative;
}


.colorthumbnail .colorzoom {
    position: absolute;
    width: 253%;
    margin-top: 6.9%;
    display: none;  
    margin-left: -3.6%;
}



.colorthumbnail:hover .colorzoom {
    display: block;
}
```

Now this appears to work fine, but because there are two different parts I want to give the user the ability to combine color options and obviously you can't hover over two images at once. After some more research I found that I need Javascript to force the `:hover` state on click. But I'm gonna be honest, I have no idea what I'm doing. This is what I have:

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<!-- -----------------------JSQuery------------------------- -->
<script>
$("#colorpicker").click(function() {
   $('.colorthumbnail:hover').toggleClass('colorthumbnail:hover .colorzoom');
});
</script>
<!------------------------ JSQuery End -------------------------->
```

However this does not appear to be working. Did I get the linked script in the `<head>` right? It did work alright with the 'Hello World' pop-up test. Did I get the classes in the script right? I'm a little stuck and help would be appreciated! Much love for the community.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your code like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#colorpicker").click(function() {
    $('.colorthumbnail:hover')
     .toggleClass('colorthumbnail:hover.colorzoom');
  });
});
```

When trying to use jquery you need to make sure the page is loaded so it can perform dom manipulation.

source: https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Here is a jsFiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Lv571n1w/

If you inspect element you can see it toggle the classes when clicked.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, although that did not seem to fix my issue. Even in the jsfiddle, after clicking `.colorthumbnail` and moving the cursor off it, `.colorzoom` disappears again (cause it only shows when `.colorthumbnail:hover` is active.

I think the problem is just that my js code is wrong but I can't for the life of me figure out why. This is my first time using jquery outside of a simple tutorial that tell you what to do step-by-step, so if anyone could point me into the right direction it'd be much appreciated!

Comment: @Feronix did you click the run button on the fiddle? Because it works as expected for me.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yeah I did, but the bigger version of the image does not remain after unhovering. I was eventually able to get it to work by using `$("#colorpicker").click(function() {` but it made it thumbnail disappear as the zoomed image showed up. I have now given up and settled on using two different jqueries (as apparently that's easier to use on one page than two of the same) to use as the top row and bottom row, while the enlarged images are loaded between the rows of thumbnails. Thank you for your help anyway, I appreciate it!